# If $49^n+16^n+k$ is divisible by 64 then find k.

Tags: induction

This question is asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136725/if-49n-16n-k-is-divisible-by-64-then-find-k?answertab=active#tab-top), but an easily grasped answer is not given (Without modular arithmetic). I'm facing the same doubt that this friend faced in $2017$:

I'll state the question here:

If "$P(n):49^n+16^n+k$ is divisible by $64$ for all $n∈N$" is true, then what is the least negative integral value of k?

The books says it is $k=-1$. But this ain't true for all $n∈N$. It's only true for $n=1$.

The previous answers on this site say no such $k$ exists. Can you explain this without using modular arithmetic.

Comment: But modular arithmetic is precisely the right tool for this sort of problem.

Comment: This is a grade $11$ question is India. It's in our syllabus but we haven't done modular arithmetic yet.

Comment: We can easily hide the modular arithmetic: Divide $k$ by $64$ by the euclidean algorithm: $k=64p+r$ for some $0\leq r\leq 63$. Then divide $49+16+k$ and $49^2+16^2+k$ by $64$. Compare the remainders and get to a contradiction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If both $49^1+16^1+k$ and $49^2+16^2+k$ are divisible by $64$, so is their difference.

Another hint: Apparently, your book is wrong.